# Start gnome-session as sudo with startup task

Tags: bash, scripts, startup

I have a startup (`task.desktop`) task located  in the `/etc/xdg/autostart` folder. It looks like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=MAAS
Comment=Metal As A Service
Exec=/home/ubuntu/initmaas.sh
Path=/home/ubuntu/
Terminal=true
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Categories=Utility;Development
```

And it starts the `initmaas.sh` script which is stored in `/home/ubuntu/initmaas.sh` directory and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -- sudo '/home/ubuntu/maas.sh'
```

Everytime I login, it asks for a prompt of the password which is fine. I give the sudo password and the task starts correctly.
My question is:

How can I make the script start automaticallly by storing he password in a variable or in a text file in the initmaas.sh file. The thing is that I need to see what it does each time I or other people login because the script does a lot of things, and also I need to reinstall it on a lot of machines. The idea is to avoid to put the password each time manually.
Any Ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: You want full time sudo access all the time? This is generally not a good idea.

Comment: hi, not full time. Just for this task. I know but Its not important. The machines are not important.